# Entity Framework Core 3.1 merge IdentityDbContext with myDbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I want to merge default identity `DbContext` with other tables (my own `DbContext`); I reverse engineered the identity `DbContext`: it provides model classes (some models are partial) and a `DbContext`:

```
namespace pakshavad.Data
{
    public partial class aspnetpakshavadContext : DbContext
    {
        public aspnetpakshavadContext()
        {
        }

        public aspnetpakshavadContext(DbContextOptions<aspnetpakshavadContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<AspNetRoleClaims> AspNetRoleClaims { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<AspNetRoles> AspNetRoles { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserClaims> AspNetUserClaims { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserLogins> AspNetUserLogins { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserRoles> AspNetUserRoles { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<AspNetUserTokens> AspNetUserTokens { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<AspNetUsers> AspNetUsers { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
#warning To protect potentially sensitive information in your connection string, you should move it out of source code. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=723263 for guidance on storing connection strings.
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=.\\MSSQLSERVER2017;Database=aspnet-pakshavad;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
            }
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetRoleClaims>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasIndex(e => e.RoleId);

                entity.Property(e => e.RoleId).IsRequired();

                entity.HasOne(d => d.Role)
                    .WithMany(p => p.AspNetRoleClaims)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.RoleId);
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetRoles>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasIndex(e => e.NormalizedName)
                    .HasName("RoleNameIndex")
                    .IsUnique()
                    .HasFilter("([NormalizedName] IS NOT NULL)");

                entity.Property(e => e.Name).HasMaxLength(256);
                entity.Property(e => e.NormalizedName).HasMaxLength(256);
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUserClaims>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasIndex(e => e.UserId);

                entity.Property(e => e.UserId).IsRequired();

                entity.HasOne(d => d.User)
                    .WithMany(p => p.AspNetUserClaims)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId);
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUserLogins>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => new { e.LoginProvider, e.ProviderKey });

                entity.HasIndex(e => e.UserId);

                entity.Property(e => e.LoginProvider).HasMaxLength(128);
                entity.Property(e => e.ProviderKey).HasMaxLength(128);
                entity.Property(e => e.UserId).IsRequired();

                entity.HasOne(d => d.User)
                    .WithMany(p => p.AspNetUserLogins)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId);
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUserRoles>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => new { e.UserId, e.RoleId });

                entity.HasIndex(e => e.RoleId);

                entity.HasOne(d => d.Role)
                    .WithMany(p => p.AspNetUserRoles)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.RoleId);

                entity.HasOne(d => d.User)
                    .WithMany(p => p.AspNetUserRoles)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId);
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUserTokens>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => new { e.UserId, e.LoginProvider, e.Name });

                entity.Property(e => e.LoginProvider).HasMaxLength(128);
                entity.Property(e => e.Name).HasMaxLength(128);

                entity.HasOne(d => d.User)
                    .WithMany(p => p.AspNetUserTokens)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId);
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<AspNetUsers>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasIndex(e => e.NormalizedEmail)
                    .HasName("EmailIndex");

                entity.HasIndex(e => e.NormalizedUserName)
                    .HasName("UserNameIndex")
                    .IsUnique()
                    .HasFilter("([NormalizedUserName] IS NOT NULL)");

                entity.Property(e => e.Email).HasMaxLength(256);

                entity.Property(e => e.NormalizedEmail).HasMaxLength(256);
                entity.Property(e => e.NormalizedUserName).HasMaxLength(256);
                entity.Property(e => e.UserName).HasMaxLength(256);
            });

            OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
        }

        partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

I copied these classes to my project. For example :

```
namespace Domain.Models.Identity
{
    public partial class AspNetUser : BaseEntity
    {
        public AspNetUser()
        {
            AspNetUserClaims = new HashSet<AspNetUserClaim>();
            AspNetUserLogins = new HashSet<AspNetUserLogin>();
            AspNetUserRoles = new HashSet<AspNetUserRole>();
            AspNetUserTokens = new HashSet<AspNetUserToken>();
        }

        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string NormalizedUserName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string NormalizedEmail { get; set; }
        public bool EmailConfirmed { get; set; }
        public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
        public string SecurityStamp { get; set; }
        public string ConcurrencyStamp { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public bool PhoneNumberConfirmed { get; set; }
        public bool TwoFactorEnabled { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset? LockoutEnd { get; set; }
        public bool LockoutEnabled { get; set; }
        public int AccessFailedCount { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<AspNetUserClaim> AspNetUserClaims { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<AspNetUserLogin> AspNetUserLogins { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<AspNetUserRole> AspNetUserRoles { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<AspNetUserToken> AspNetUserTokens { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class AspNetUserConfigure : IEntityTypeConfiguration<AspNetUser>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<AspNetUser> builder)
        {
            builder.HasIndex(e => e.NormalizedEmail)
                    .HasName("EmailIndex");

            builder.HasIndex(e => e.NormalizedUserName)
                .HasName("UserNameIndex")
                .IsUnique()
                .HasFilter("([NormalizedUserName] IS NOT NULL)");

            builder.Property(e => e.Email).HasMaxLength(256);

            builder.Property(e => e.NormalizedEmail).HasMaxLength(256);

            builder.Property(e => e.NormalizedUserName).HasMaxLength(256);

            builder.Property(e => e.UserName).HasMaxLength(256);
        }
    }
}
```

and in `MyDbContext` (in another class library), in my project I use reflection, and `IEntityTypeConfiguration` interface for automatically creating DbSets :

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var entitiesAssembly = typeof(IEntity).Assembly;

        modelBuilder.RegisterAllEntities<IEntity>(entitiesAssembly);
        modelBuilder.RegisterEntityTypeConfiguration(entitiesAssembly);
        modelBuilder.AddRestrictDeleteBehaviorConvention();
        modelBuilder.AddSequentialGuidForIdConvention();
        modelBuilder.AddPluralizingTableNameConvention();

        OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
    }

    partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
}
```

but for

```
partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
```

method, I get an error:

> A partial method must be declared within a partial class, partial struct, or partial interface

I have no idea how to fix this error. Can somebody help me?

And a second question: does my `DbContext` need to inherit from `IdentityDbContext` class or not?

Comment: `I want to merge default identity DbContext with other tables (my DbContext)` why?

Comment: `;` change to `{}` You have to implement the method not end it with a semicolon.

Comment: @lanKemp, i don't want to separate two databases, one for identity and another for my tables. and default Identity has only one migration for creating the database, but I want to have models for the next migrations.

Comment: @Train not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are asking whether you should inherit your class from `IdentityDbContext` at all, my answer would be a big resounding **yes please**. By doing that you will free yourself from having to decompile library code and support it yourself. Microsoft and the Community do good enough job maintaining it for you - save your time. So this hopefully solves your first question as well.

As far as I can see, you've copied all `DbSet` properties and most `AspNetUserConfigure` from stock standard libraries. For this answer I'll assume you want to override some behaviour and add that `.HasFilter("([NormalizedUserName] IS NOT NULL)")` into your `AspNetUser`.

```
public class aspnetpakshavadContext: IdentityDbContext {
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("your-connection-string"); // you will notice I removed .IsConfigured check - I believe this is redundant as OnConfiguring should always have it set to `false`
        }
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder); // this is calling all relevant code from IdentityDbContext that you have previously copied. Yours will go afterwards to ensure your changes are applied last
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new MyAspNetUserConfiguration());// your extension point to modify particular entity model     
    }

    public class MyAspNetUserConfiguration: IEntityTypeConfiguration<PortalUser>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<AspNetUser> builder)
        {
            builder.HasFilter("([NormalizedUserName] IS NOT NULL)"); // Builders are chained, so as long as you've called this after base method `OnModelCreating` above - this should add to existing model.
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully this is what you're after.

On a side note, I am not sure where your partial implementation come from, as the original code for [`IdentityDbContext`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Identity/EntityFrameworkCore/src/IdentityDbContext.cs) does not seem to have any...

Comment: reverse Engineering with `Scaffold-DbContext` it created partial classes.

Comment: Oh, okay, so you scaffolded your dbcontext then -I've not seen the resulting implementation so can't be 100% certain. I do however still believe you can simply reinherit it from `IdentityDbContext` should you so desire